# Is there a way to customize TabNavigation to achieve something like on the Revolut app?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement a navigation like on this gif using react-navigation:

[image: Revolut navigation example]

I think that I may be able to modify the [TabNavigation component from react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/) but I'm not really sure if it's the best way to achieve something like that.

I'm not really looking for the exact answer, just the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found a way to do this.

I'm using the library [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view). The doc is quite easy to understand, and the `<TabView />` component easy to customize.

I hope that it will help someone :)